# force format when parsing dates in pandas from an Excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, date

I am trying to parse dates from an Excel file following a given format `%d/%m/%y`. I am not able to set the format, I am always getting `%m/%d/%Y`.

The source format is `%d/%m/%y` so that the first date should be first of June 2016. Any ideas on how to do it?

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/8gqmq3jx27unsta/example_dates.xlsx?dl=1'

file = pd.ExcelFile(url, parse_date=True, 
       date_parser = (lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format ='%d/%m/%y')))

df = file.parse(0)

df
    date    variable
0   2016-01-06  1
1   2016-06-07  2
2   2016-12-10  3
3   2016-12-29  4
```

Something like this might work but it doesn't:

```
df = file.parse(0, converters={'date' : lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, dayfirst=True)}

date    variable
0   2016-01-06  1
1   2016-06-07  2
2   2016-12-10  3
3   2016-12-29  4
```

Comment: @Mandy8055 Nothing happens after applying `pd.to_datetime(df.Date,dayfirst=True)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `converters`:

```
>>> file.parse(0, parse_dates=True, index_col=0, date_parser=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))

     variable
date    
2016-06-01  1
2016-07-06  2
2016-10-12  3
2016-12-29  4
```

Comment: Do you know how to do it when you don't have the variable names?

Comment: You should just be able to use `0` or whatever the index of that column is for the key. so `converters={0: lambda x....}`

Comment: the first date, for instance, is 1/6/16 (first of June, 2016), but what I get is 6th of January, right? Even if a change the format.

Comment: Yes, in this format it's going to appear as January 6th. There's no way to automatically detect if it's wrong, at least with these numbers. A human can't even tell they're wrong. You'll have to go in and manually change it.

Comment: Can't I force a given format when reading the data like in R?

Comment: That's what we're doing already, but there is no reason to think that the first date should be June when all the other dates are in Y/m/d format.

Comment: The idea would be to say to the parser that the first number always has to be the day, the second the month, and the third the year. The source format is consistent, my problem is I don't know how to read it correctly. Can I do that?

Comment: `pd.to_datetime('01-06-16', dayfirst=True)` should do the trick, but doesn't work when I put it into the converters.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, pandas have a format to display datetime object. So, it will display in that format till you change that. Meanwhile, you can do this:

```
>>> df['date1'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%y')
          date  variable       date1
0   2016-01-06         1    06/01/16
1   2016-06-07         2    07/06/16
2   2016-12-10         3    10/12/16
3   2016-12-29         4    29/12/16
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pandas.read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) in combination with [`datetime.datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime).

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

URL = 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/8gqmq3jx27unsta/example_dates.xlsx?dl=1'

file = (
    pd
    .read_excel(
        io=URL, 
        parse_date=True,
        date_parser=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%Y'),
    )
)
```